# Continually fade background box with each click of the fade button

Tags: javascript, html

Brand new to coding.  Trying to get "fade" button to fade a little more each time I click it.
I have used this code to grow and shrink the box and I was trying to do the same thing for the opacity:

```js
document.getElementById("growbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var growVariable = 10;
  var newValueHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").style.height)

  document.getElementById("box").style.height = newValueHeight + growVariable + "px";

  var newValueWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").style.width)
  document.getElementById("box").style.width = newValueWidth + growVariable + "px";

});


document.getElementById("fadebutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var opVariable = .2;
  var newOpValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").style.opacity)
  document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = newValueHeight - opVariable;
});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 150px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 5px; width:150px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; background-color:orange; margin:50px"></div>
<button id="fadebutton">Fade</button>
<button id="growbutton">Grow</button>
```

Can you tell me what I'm missing so the box fades .2 with each click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `parseFloat` when dealing with non-whole numbers or with decimal points as `parseInt` returns an integer or a whole number

```js
document.getElementById("fadebutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var opVariable = .2;
  let box = document.getElementById("box")
  let currentOpacity = parseFloat(box.style.opacity)

  box.style.opacity = currentOpacity - .2


});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 150px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 5px; width:150px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; background-color:orange; margin:50px;opacity:1"></div>

<button id="fadebutton">
Fade
</button>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! this worked but only after I hit the reset button.  If I refresh the page it doesn't work unless I hit the "reset" button.  Then it fades incrementally.   You got any ideas why it would do that?   And thank you again.

Comment: I got it.  Awesome!  I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code produces the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: newValueHeight is not defined`. There were a few issues:

1. You were referencing `newValueHeight` instead of `newOpValue` by accident.
2. `parseInt()` will return an *integer*, i.e., if the current opacity is 0.8, `parseInt(0.8)` returns `1`. You need to use `parseFloat()` to get a floating point back.
3. Initially, `style.opacity` is `undefined` because it has not been set yet. You should use `opValue = ... || 1` so that it defaults to 1 if not yet set.

```js
let box = document.getElementById('box'),
    fadeBtn = document.getElementById('fadebutton'),
    growBtn = document.getElementById('growbutton');

growBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let growVariable = 10,
      boxHeight = parseInt(box.style.height),
      boxWidth = parseInt(box.style.width);

  box.style.height = boxHeight + growVariable + "px",
  box.style.width = boxWidth + growVariable + "px";
  
});

fadeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let opVariable = .2,
      opValue = parseFloat(box.style.opacity) || 1;
  
  box.style.opacity = opValue - opVariable;
  
});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 100px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 5px; width:100px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; background-color:orange; margin:1rem"></div>
<button id="fadebutton">Fade</button>
<button id="growbutton">Grow</button>
```

Comment: @Billy4C No worries. Multiple people responded to this question, please accept an answer if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fade the image onclick, you can simply decrement the `style.opacity` property. Something like this:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('#box');

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.id === 'fadebutton') {
    if (box.style.opacity > 0) {
      box.style.opacity -= .2;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 150px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 5px; width:150px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; background-color:orange; margin:50px; opacity: 1"></div>
<button id="fadebutton">Fade</button>
```

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("fadebutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //var opVariable = .2;
  let box = document.getElementById("box")
  let currentOpacity = parseFloat(box.style.opacity)

  box.style.opacity = currentOpacity - .2


});
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 150px; max-height: 600px; min-height: 5px; width:150px; max-width: 600px; min-width: 5px; background-color:orange; margin:50px;opacity:1"></div>

<button id="fadebutton">
Fade
</button>
```